# How to test AWS

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, aws, qa-architect

This is an open question. I know no answer is wrong or correct. If someone asks this question in an interview He wants to understand your thinking process.
Can anyone put a light on this, how to answer this question?

Comment: I'm not certain this is off topic. It might be subjective, but there are good subjective questions. I won't mod-hammer this open, but I would consider re-evaluating whether or not it is off topic or not.

Answer (score 1):

I like to answers questions with questions during interviews.
My first response would be that the question "How to test AWS?" is very broad.

My first question would be: Which part of AWS should I test?

> As of 2020, AWS comprises more than 175 products and services
> including computing, storage, networking, database, analytics,
> application services, deployment, management, mobile, developer tools,
> and tools for the Internet of Things.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services

Dear interviewer did you mean to ask *"how-to test this application deployed on AWS?"* instead.

Maybe you care to explain how your application is deployed to AWS first? Testing is very depended on context, so to truly answer your question I need to understand your context first.

Maybe we can draw the high level architecture on a white-board and I can ask some critical thinking questions and identify some risks.

Comment: Wouldn't this work better as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @LeeJensen No, this is how I would respond during an interview that asks such a broad open question. These are not questions for the OP to ask for clarification :)

Comment: That's fair. Gives it more context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34373)

Comment: @JAINAM I read the question as how to respond during an interview, my answers fits that. I am not asking for information from the author. I updated my answer to reflect that better.

Comment: @JAINAM The author asks for our thinking process in answering an open question like this. Maybe you misinterpret the original question, or maybe I did :)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal Ahh Okay. Now it makes sense.